# Why we use static methods in Routeconfig , Bundle config classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

All the methods we use in global.asax are static methods ? Like for Route Config, Bundle config, Dependecy resolver etc.. What is the reason behind it?

```
   protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        InitHandleBarHelpers();
        Services.AutoMapperBootstrap.Init();
    }
```

Comment: why not static?

Answer (score 2):

All the Configurations classes like AreaRegistration, FilterConfig, RouteConfig, BundleConfig, GlobalConfiguration are static classes and an application can  only have singleton configurations, imagine a scenario where you ever have instantiate all the configurations for a new session.....
When Application start for the first time all the necessary configurations are loaded and remain same until application Stopped.